# I would like to learn how to wrap this ''ziptie'' around my weapon model

Tags: modeling

Alright so like the title says i would love to learn this stuff and youtube tutorials have not been helpful at all so far and my online search has been a failure so why not make a post myself! i import weapon models into games and lately i have wanted to add more details onto the models with tape or zipties or pads etc and ive got some models ready but i am just curious now as to how i could wrap these things neatly around certain parts of a model!
Here is an example of the item i am trying to wrap onto a specific part of this gun!
[image]

when using the shrinkwrap modifier i get results like this, it flattens the object and does not really project nicely around the actual edges etc, im A HUGE BEGINNER when it comes to blender and i only really use it for preparing the models for a game! of course i do not expect it to be as easy as adding a modifier which is why i am here to get some real help! [image]

File [here](https://pasteall.org/blend/0712c20f5b094128b1cc921b804a6dee).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *Shrinkwrap* modifier (in this case add a *Solidify* modifier in order to give thickness), but you can simply model your strap:

Select and duplicate an edge of your gun:

[image]

Extrude it to give it width, scale it up a bit:

[image]

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals*:

[image]

Choose the front view and use the *Shear* tool to twist your shape a bit (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>):

[image]

Duplicate and shear again:

[image]

If you want more control on the shape, create additional edge loops <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>:

[image]

The kind of result you can get:

[image]

Comment: well this was very helpful thank you, was hoping there would be an easier way to apply what i had already made! the shrinkwrap modifier didnt work too well and wont really apply properly for me along the mesh! i would be happy to send the files over to take a look at?

Comment: you can upload your file on https://pasteall.org/blend/ upload then copy the URL it has generated and paste it here

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/0712c20f5b094128b1cc921b804a6dee

Should be it? i left the parts where i was intending to put wrap them around, thanks again for the quick answers

Comment: I can't make it work properly with a Shrinkwrap, it always tweak in a weird, I'm not sure you'll get anything good, but maybe someone will be able to help, if you don't succeed maybe use my method instead